# Why does rust require explicit lifetimes for mutable references but not regular reference?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

Here is a simple example of where you only need to specify the lifetime for a mutable reference:

```rust
fn foo<'a>(x: &'a [&'a i32]) -> impl Iterator<Item = ()> + 'a {
    x.iter().map(|_| ())
}

fn foo_mut<'a>(x: &'a mut [&'a i32]) -> impl Iterator<Item = ()> + 'a {
    x.iter().map(|_| ())
}

fn bar(x: &[&i32]) {
    for _ in foo(x) {}
}

// why is an explicit lifetime needed?
fn bar_mut<'a>(x: &'a mut [&'a i32]) {
    for _ in foo_mut(x) {}
}
```

I would like to not have to specify these lifetimes because it make it much more difficult to call the function.

Is this just some compiler bug or am I missing something?

You can work around this by using a macro but I would really like to be able to define this as a function without specifying the lifetime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, lets talk about [lifetime elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html). All references have some lifetime associated with them, but Rust allows you to elide the annotation when it can appropriately inferred.

If you were to write:

```
fn bar_mut(x: &mut [&i32]) {
    for _ in foo_mut(x) {}
}
```

The compiler would infer each reference to have its own lifetime:

```
fn bar_mut<'a, 'b>(x: &'a mut [&'b i32]) {
    for _ in foo_mut(x) {}
}
```

As you can see, the signature of `bar_mut` is different than the signature of `foo_mut`; the lifetime of the slice, `&[_]` doesn't have to match the lifetime of its elements, `&i32`, so it can't satisfy the constraints set by `foo_mut`.

---

So why does it work for `foo` and `bar`?

Second, lets talk about [variance](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/subtyping.html). Lifetimes in particular can be adjusted by the compiler (according to their variance) usually to the minimal frame to which they are needed. Typically, references' lifetimes are called *covariant* which means the compiler can shorten them as needed.

If we look at `bar` with explicit lifetimes:

```
fn bar<'a, 'b>(x: &'a [&'b i32]) {
    for _ in foo(x) {}
}
```

The `'b` lifetime is shortened to match `'a` when passing `x` to `foo` and it can do that because `'b` is covariant. There is also an implied `'b: 'a` constraint due to the construction of nested references which makes this guaranteed to be valid but that's not important at the moment.

However, *mutable* references are a bit more strict since their content can be re-assigned. The lifetime of a mutable reference is still covariant, but the type it *references* must be *invariant*. Otherwise you would be able to assign via that reference a value that lives shorter than it actually needs. So if we look at your signature for `foo_mut`:

```
fn foo_mut<'a>(x: &'a mut [&'a i32]) -> ...
```

The lifetime associated with the slice, `&mut [_]`, can be covariant but the lifetime of the element, `&i32`, *must* be invariant because it is behind a mutable reference. Thus `'a` is invariant. So when we look at `bar_mut` with different lifetimes:

```
fn bar_mut<'a, 'b>(x: &'a mut [&'b i32]) {
    for _ in foo_mut(x) {}
}
```

The lifetime `'b` is likewise invariant so it stays the same when passing to `foo_mut`. And since `foo_mut` requires the lifetimes to be the same, `'a` must match `'b`. And `'b` cannot be shortened, so `'a` must be *extended* but that is not allowed since `'a` is only *covariant* (i.e. it can only be shortened). This is how you get the error:

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:15:14
   |
14 | fn bar_mut<'a, 'b>(x: &'a mut [&'b i32]) {
   |            --  -- lifetime `'b` defined here
   |            |
   |            lifetime `'a` defined here
15 |     for _ in foo_mut(x) {}
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^ argument requires that `'a` must outlive `'b`
```

---

> I would really like to be able to define this as a function without specifying the lifetime.

You're only in this pickle because `foo` and `foo_mut` are needlessly over constrained. If you annotate the lifetimes to only what is needed, you don't have this issue at all:

```
fn foo<'a>(x: &'a [&i32]) -> impl Iterator<Item = ()> + 'a {
    x.iter().map(|_| ())
}

fn foo_mut<'a>(x: &'a mut [&i32]) -> impl Iterator<Item = ()> + 'a {
    x.iter().map(|_| ())
}

fn bar(x: &[&i32]) {
    for _ in foo(x) {}
}

fn bar_mut(x: &mut [&i32]) {
    for _ in foo_mut(x) {}
}
```

As shown you only need the outer lifetime because that's what your iterator type relies on. It technically also relies on the lifetime of `&i32` but because nested references lifetimes are inherently constrained, you get that for free. You do still need the `'a` because you need to tell the compiler what your `impl Iterator` is allowed to reference.

The key is that you should use different lifetimes whenever possible and elide when being explicit is unnecessary. Full code on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=88f678776dc0c6dfc346caa1b498f824).

---

As a final note: because `&'a mut [&'a i32]` is overconstraining, you would later encounter issues *using* `bar_mut`. For example, you wouldn't be able to call it twice on the same value. See that failure on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9e9e0e3aca1f4183d6b27ba81a38c796). See [Why does this mutable borrow live beyond its scope?](/q/66252831/2189130) that explains a bit more in a different scenario.

Comment: Thank you! This was actually really helpful. 

I intentionally simplified my example but I don't think I would be able to avoid having nested lifetimes because I am storing a mutable reference in a struct. It looks like it might be easier to use a Rc<RefCell<_>> to accomplish what I wanted to do.